# Pause a running script in Mac terminal and then resume later

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

How can I pause (not stop) a running script from Terminal in OSX, to resume it later from the point it paused?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To complement [devnull's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20650068/45375) and [DavidW's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20663072/45375) helpful answers:
Here are **convenience functions for suspending (pausing) / resuming a script by name**, from *any* shell (not just the one that started the script):

Pass the script's filename(s) (*without* path):

`suspend-script someScript ...`

and later:

`resume-script someScript ...`

Update: Added additional function for *killing* a script by name: `kill-script someScript ...`

- Works with scripts run by either `bash` or `sh` (which is effectively just a `bash` alias on macOS).
- If multiple instances of a script are running, only the most recently started is targeted.
- Exit code will be non-zero in case of failure (including not finding a running script by the given name).
- `suspend-script` and `resume-script`: if a script process is already in the desired state, no operation is performed (and no error is reported).

Functions (e.g., place them in `~/.bash_profile`):

```
suspend-script() {
  [[ -z $1 || $1 == '-h' || $1 == '--help' ]] && { echo "Usage: $FUNCNAME scriptFileName ..."$'\n'"Suspends the specified bash/sh script(s)."; return $(( ${#1} == 0 )); }
  local ec=0
  for p in "$@"; do
    pkill -STOP -nf '/?(bash|sh)[ ]+(.*/)?'"$p"'( |$)' \
      && echo "'$1' suspended." \
      || { ec=$?; echo "ERROR: bash/sh script process not found: '$p'" 1>&2; }
  done
  return $ec
}

resume-script() {
  [[ -z $1 || $1 == '-h' || $1 == '--help' ]] && { echo "Usage: $FUNCNAME scriptFileName ..."$'\n'"Resumes the specified bash/sh script(s)."; return $(( ${#1} == 0 )); }
  local ec=0
  for p in "$@"; do
    pkill -CONT -nf '/?(bash|sh)[ ]+(.*/)?'"$p"'( |$)' \
     && echo "'$1' resumed." \
     || { ec=$?; echo "ERROR: bash/sh script process not found: '$p'" 1>&2; }
  done
  return $ec
}

kill-script() {
  [[ -z $1 || $1 == '-h' || $1 == '--help' ]] && { echo "Usage: $FUNCNAME scriptFileName ..."$'\n'"Kills the specified bash/sh script(s)."; return $(( ${#1} == 0 )); }
  local ec=0
  for p in "$@"; do
    pkill -nf '/?(bash|sh)[ ]+(.*/)?'"$p"'( |$)' \
     && echo "'$1' killed." \
     || { ec=$?; echo "ERROR: bash/sh script process not found: '$p'" 1>&2; }
  done
  return $ec
}
```

Comment: Thanks but imagine, I am executing a set of commands (say through pipes or ;). Is there a way to pause it when there is no name associated for it?

Comment: @JikkuJose: Your best bet is to wrap such commands in a script. Otherwise, each script executed as part of the multi-command string or pipe will show as a *separate* process and you couldn't target the thing as a whole. Also note that with `;`-separated commands a subsequent command will not start until the preceding one either terminates or explicitly starts a background task. Also note that I fixed minor bugs in the functions and added a `kill-script` function.

Answer (score 74):

If you're using BASH as the shell (which is the default shell on a Mac), you can use BASH's built in *job control* capabilities.

If the script is running in the foreground of your terminal, you can press <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> to pause the script. This will *suspend* the running of the script.

To restart it, type `jobs` and you'll see the suspended *job* listed there. Type `fg` or more specific `fg %x` where `x` is the number of the suspended *job*.

```
$ test.pl   # Test script (prints out Foo every two seconds
Foo!
Foo!
^Z
$  # Job has been suspended
$ jobs
[1] + Stopped                  ./test.pl
$ fg %1  #Restarts Job #1
Foo!
```

The *Control-Z* key that suspends the job is the default, but could be modified. The [stty](http://man.cx/stty) can change this and will show you the current default:

```
$ stty -a     
speed 9600 baud; 40 rows; 120 columns;
lflags: icanon isig iexten echo echoe -echok echoke -echonl echoctl
        -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho pendin -nokerninfo
        -extproc
iflags: -istrip icrnl -inlcr -igncr ixon -ixoff ixany imaxbel iutf8
        -ignbrk brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
oflags: opost onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -dsrflow
        -dtrflow -mdmbuf
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
        eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^H; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
        min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
        stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;
```

You can see the very last line has `susp = ^Z`. This is the key that will *suspend* your script. In this case, it's *Control-Z*.

You can also use the `bg` command to make a suspended *job* run in the background. However, that background job will terminate when you close the shell/Terminal Window unless you had prepended [nohup](http://man.cx/nohup) to the front of the command.

Comment: I think this deserves the tick

Comment: Excellent! This definitely deserves to be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 12):

Find the process ID of the running script.

To stop (or what you refer to as *pause*) the script, say:

```
kill -SIGSTOP PID
```

To resume the stopped (or *paused*) process, say:

```
kill -SIGCONT PID
```

(where `PID` refers to the numeric process ID.)

Comment: In addition to that, possibly, but not always, he can also press Ctrl-Z to pause, and later run `fg` to continue.

Comment: @janos You're right, but as you've mentioned _but not always_.

Comment: @janos can you provide some pointers to search for more information on the solution you mentioned? Would like to read about the edge cases you mentioned.

Comment: @JikkuJose you can read about what I mentioned in the **JOB CONTROL** section of `man bash`

Answer (score 2):

`echo Press any key to continue...
read blah`

Then just don't do anything with the variable.
This is as close to the `pause` functionality that I've used in DOS batch scripts that I've come across.

Comment: Most straightforward! Can also put in one line: `echo Press any key to continue...; read blah`. And you can also define an alias in `.zshrc` like this: `alias pause="echo Press any key to continue...; read blah"` :)

Comment: Although I think this should be more of `Press return to continue...` because other keys don't seem to continue. (PS: Alias will not work in scripts. It only works on the terminal itself.)