# How to run Script per shortcut

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I have a Terminal cmd running that executes a function from the .bash_profile file (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20649783/pause-a-running-script-in-mac-terminal-and-then-resume-later)).

From the description, I added the function to the `~/.bash_profile` (can be found here `/home/user/.bash_profile`)

From my Terminal everything works !

But how do I create a shortcut in Mac OS that executes this Terminal cmd ??

I tried Apple Automator (--> but error: `Cmd not found`)

I tried Alfred (--> but same error: `Cmd not found`)

How can I make this Terminal cmd execute from a keyboard-shortcut ??

Do I need to place the script-functions in another file (other than bash_profile ?) - or what is here to do ?

Here is an image of the Automator trial:

[image]

Comment: Try using `. /Users/myName/...` (notice the preceding dot and lack of quotes). I am out of ideas if that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Open Automator, choose Application, add a Run Shell Script action and put in your Shell command between quotes (if you have a file, you can just drag and drop it).

Other than playing it, now you can save it (as an app anywhere) and even set the icon. Then you got an app and then you can define a keyboard shortcut for it in system-preferences.app

### This should work, at least it does for me.

make sure your script is executable: `sudo chmod u+x <your-scriptname>`
and also add the filename extension `.command` to your filename. So the name of the script should be `filename.command`.
When you then click the script in Finder, it gets executed.

I hope that works!

Comment: The Run Shell script action "with or without quote" reveals `No such file or directory`. Again, it works inside the Terminal - but it does not inside Automator ! (see image in original question)

Answer (score 0):

Place the functions in separate files, such as `suspend-script.sh`, `resume-script.sh`, and `kill-script.sh`; put them in a common directory like `/home/user/scripts`. To keep using them in your `.bash_history`, do:

```
# in .bash_history
source "suspend-script.sh"
source "resume-script.sh"
source "kill-script.sh"
```

Make sure you set the executable bit on each script (`chmod +x /home/user/scripts/*.sh`). Then, use the following for shortcut keybindings:

```
/home/user/scripts/suspend-script.sh thing_to_suspend
/home/user/scripts/resume-script.sh thing_to_resume
/home/user/scripts/kill-script.sh thing_to_kill
```

Since it's a shortcut to a function, you have to pick *one* script to suspend/resume/kill (the thing* above).

For example, if you wanted to suspend/resume/kill the `top` process, you would use the following:

```
/home/user/scripts/suspend-script.sh top
/home/user/scripts/resume-script.sh top
/home/user/scripts/kill-script.sh top
```

Comment: thank you - I did not get two of your points: Nr1: Did I understand correctly to add the three 'source'-lines to the .bash_history file ?? Nr2: what did you mean by "Since it's a shortcut to a function, you have to pick one script to suspend/resume/kill (the thing* above)." How do I execute one of the three now by a keyboard-shortcut ??

Comment: #1: Yes. #2: I meant that you have to bind one script to a different keyboard shortcut, and you can only ever suspend/resume/kill one process. So, these keybindings won't suspend/resume/kill any process, only just the one you specify in the keyboard shortcut

Comment: ah - I understand. But I am no further than at the beginning - because running `"/Users/myName/scripts/suspend-script.sh myProcessName"` (including the quotes or without) in the Automator reveals `No such file or directory`!

Comment: Did you create the scripts directory, and add the scripts to that directory?

Comment: Yes, the only difference to your solution: I placed everything inside `/Users/myName/` instead of `/home/user/` - the rest is identical. I have a scripts-folder in my `/Users/myName/` folder and placed the three *.sh-scripts in there... I also executed the `chmod +x /User/myName/scripts/*.sh` cmd ...

Comment: Is the error message just "No such file or directory"?